# RSA Key Export and Import

Tags: go, import, export, rsa, x509

I'm currently trying to export my created keys and than importing them to use them.

But if I run my code I get the following error:

```
panic: x509: only RSA and ECDSA public keys supported

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /path/to/project/src/main.go:19 +0x3bd
```

This is my current code:

```
// Create key
key, _ := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)

// Message to encrypt
message := "hi stackoverflow"

priv := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key)
pub, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(key.PublicKey)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

private, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(priv)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    return
}

public, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pub)
if err != nil {
    return
}

encrypted, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, public.(*rsa.PublicKey), []byte(message))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
dencrypted, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, private, encrypted)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(dencrypted))
```

(I researched like the hole internet but didn't found something, maybe I used a wrong search term.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton line 19: public, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(pub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this, I get the panic on `MarshalPKIXPublicKey` (not `ParsePKIXPublicKey` as you were suggesting in comment above).

The problem is that the function accepts a `*rsa.PublicKey` and you're passing a plain `rsa.PublicKey`.

This works for me: `pub, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(&key.PublicKey)`.

Comment: I love you man! Thank you so much. I was working on this for months (I’m a going to school and this is for a school project).

Comment: The key to figuring this out was to read the source code. Quite simple once you see the method that constructs the error and compare it to what you’re passing in :-).